# how to make v-for return one word plus the previous word vue

Tags: javascript, loops, vue.js, for-loop, vuejs2

good afternoon, I'm practicing with vue, how can I make a for loop return me word by word plus the previous one.

```
<div v-for="option in this.options.split(' ')" :key="tag" >
 <h2>{{option}}</h2>
</div>

data() {
return {
  options:'the green house'
}
},
```

and now returns

```
the 
green
house
```

and I would like you to return

```
the
the green
the green house
```

how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a `computed` property to avoid cluttering your template with logic. Then, you can use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return { options: 'the green house' };
  },
  computed: {
    optionsArray() {
      return this.options.split(' ')
           .map((_, i, arr) => arr.slice(0, i + 1).join(' '));
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.21/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <div v-for="option in optionsArray" :key="option">
     <h2>{{option}}</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `computed` property that returns the expected list as follows:

```js
new Vue({ 
  el:"#app", 
  data: () => ({ options: 'the green house' }),
  computed: {
    myOptions() {
      const list = this.options.split(' ');
      return list.map((option, i) => list.slice(0, i+1).join(' '));
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(option, index) in myOptions" :key="index">
    <h2>{{option}}</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```